# Why the generated Queries by ormLite to load related references using IN do not use parameterized queries?

Tags: servicestack

I have an issue related to loading reference/child tables when loading the parent table records from the database. My DB engine is MS SQL Server. I'm using ServiceStack.OrmLite v5.8.0. My application is written in C# .NET v4.6.2.

I have three entities, 1 parent and 2 children. They are marked properly using the required annotations by OrmLite. I noticed when running a query from C# to fetch the parent table including the children in one shot using an IN Condition, the queries that get generated to load the children records are not parameterized. Please have a look at the queries I got from SQL Profiler below:

1. This is the first query that fetches the records from the parent table. Notice the usage of the parameterized query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "Id", "MeetingDateAndTime", "Location", "IsHeld", "ScheduledForDate", "ContactMeBy", "IsCanceled", "IncidentId", "IncidentNumber", "IncidentDateTime" 
FROM "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetings"
WHERE "Id" IN (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10)
ORDER BY "IncidentDateTime" DESC',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int,@9 int,@10 int',@0=16,@1=15,@2=13,@3=14,@4=12,@5=8,@6=5,@7=6,@8=4,@9=1,@10=2
```

2. This is the second query that fetches the records from the first child table. Notice the usage of the hard-coded values while the parameters are being generated:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "Id", "ResolutionSessionIdFk", "Type", "RespondentId", "FirstName", "LastName" FROM "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetingsInvitees" WHERE "ResolutionSessionIdFk" IN (SELECT "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetings"."Id" 
FROM "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetings"
WHERE "Id" IN (16,15,13,14,12,8,5,6,4,1,2))',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int,@9 int,@10 int',@0=16,@1=15,@2=13,@3=14,@4=12,@5=8,@6=5,@7=6,@8=4,@9=1,@10=2
```

3. This is the third query that fetches the records from the second child table. Notice the usage of the hard-coded values while the parameters are being generated:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT "Id", "ResolutionMeetingIdFk", "Type", "FirstName", "LastName" FROM "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetingsOfficers" WHERE "ResolutionMeetingIdFk" IN (SELECT "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetings"."Id" 
FROM "HomePageSearch_ResolutionMeetings"
WHERE "Id" IN (16,15,13,14,12,8,5,6,4,1,2))',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int,@9 int,@10 int',@0=16,@1=15,@2=13,@3=14,@4=12,@5=8,@6=5,@7=6,@8=4,@9=1,@10=2
```

Any idea why?

Comment: It's the result of the sub queries being rasterized inline when merged into the main query to isolate them from paging and ambiguous columns from custom select expressions, what's the actual issue that you're running into?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My issue is with the fact that the second and the third queries as mentioned in my original question above, they have the IN Clause generated with hard-coded values, and parameters as well. These parameters are not used. They are just there. It is different than the first query. Any idea why?

Comment: The reason is because the subquery is rasterized & the other params could be used by other parts of the main query so it's unlikely they can be erased, but can you provide a [stand-alone query on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=0cd558e817f28f77b974c44c3e12ff6f) that has the behavior you're referring to so I can inspect it.